# old info in db not displaying when new info is added via CSV - phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, phpmyadmin

I am trying to upload a csv file into phpMyAdmin, this is quite simple, and the data goes to the correct columns, but then the old data does not show.

The database is called "dogoodmapdb", with tables map - `place_id, name, address, lat, lng, email, phone, bio, type, area, country, need, capture_id` and users - `user_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone`

The MAP table holds data to go on a google map at this website: `www.dogoodmap.org` and it already has around 260 places on it.

Currently we have to upload each place individually, so I need to be able to upload a csv file into the phpMyAdmin to get it to run faster!

I have a csv with the needed data, an headings. When I insert it into phpMyAdmin, it works fine, the places appear in the database, but then NOTHING on the map shows. Then I have to delete them, once I have deleted all of them, the old data shows.

I have also looked at tutorials using php script that pulls the info from the csv file and `INSERT TO` into the database, and I have re-written about 6 different tutorial scripts, but none of them work.

I have looked around for answers, but it seems to me that I am the only one experiencing this issue. I have checked for any possible errors in the csv file, there are non. I have checked the delimiter, and it looks fine. It uploads to the database, but then it wont let any data show.

Please help me. We have around 2000-3000 places in a csv file, but do not have the time to upload individually!

Thanks in advance

Comment: A couple of things come to mind. Is the data going to the correct fields when you import the csv file? Is the problem in the code that displays the map rather than in the data on the database?

Comment: I have checked every entry in the database (the new ones from the csv file) and all is fine and in the correct fields. The code is perfect as it still pulls the information if we submit it via the form as an individual submission. So I think it has to be with phpMyAdmin or uploading the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try with sql load data infile http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html.

Example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```